# C++: Check istream has non-space, non-tab, non-newline characters left without extracting chars

Tags: c++, iostream

I am reading a std::istream and I need to verify without extracting characters that:

1. The stream is not "empty", i.e. that trying to read a char will not result in an fail state (solved by using peek() member function and checking fail state, then setting back to original state)
2. That among the characters left there is at least one which is not a space, a tab or a newline char.

The reason for this is, is that I am reading text files containing say one int per line, and sometimes there may be extra spaces / new-lines at the end of the file and this causes issues when I try get back the data from the file to a vector of int.

A peek(int n) would probably do what I need but I am stuck with its implementation.
I know I could just read istream like:

```
while (myInt << myIstream) {…} //Will fail when I am at the end
```

but the same check would fail for a number of different conditions (say I have something which is not an int on some line) and being able to differentiate between the two reading errors (unexpected thing, nothing left) would help me to write more robust code, as I could write:

```
while (something_left(myIstream)) {
  myInt << myIstream;
  if (myStream.fail()) {…} //Horrible things happened
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: So you have something like: 1\n,2\n\n3\n, and you need to read the numbers but not any spaces/extraneous newlines/etc.?

Comment: I used integers in the question to make an example, but I am dealing with arbitrary data. I just need to separate "errors" due to incorrect data matching (say a double has been stored and I am trying to get back an integer, i.e. stream not in expected format) to "errors" due to nothing relevant (i.e. everything not space char or alike) being left in stream. In the case of vectors of int yes, that's the problem I need to solve (no ',' between the numbers, just "spaces").

Comment: That's not how you read from a stream.  The stream MUST be on the left-hand side of the shift operator.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yes you are right, sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what I did to skip whitespace/detect EOF before the actual input:

```
char c;
if (!(cin >> c)) //skip whitespace
    return false;  // EOF or other error
cin.unget();
```

This is independent of what data you are going to read.

This code relies on the `skipws` manipulator being set by default for standard streams, but it can be set manually `cin >> skipw >> c;`

Answer (score 2):

There is a function called ws which eats whitespace.  Perhaps you could call that after each read.  If that hits eof, then you know you've got a normal termination.  If it doesn't and the next read doesn't produce a valid int, then you know you've got garbage in your file.  Maybe something like:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("test.dat");
    while (infile)
    {
        int i;
        infile >> i;
        if (!infile.fail())
            std::cout << i << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "garbage\n";
        ws(infile);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's my understanding ws would eat spaces and tabs, would it eat newlines (std::endl) as well?

Comment: Yes, ws eats newlines too.  Additionally it will consider anything as whitespace as defined by the currently installed locale on the istream.

Answer (score 1):

And simple

```
for(;;){
  if(!(myIstream >> myInt)){
    if(myIstream.eof()) {
     //end of file
    }else{
     //not an integer
    }
  }

  // Do something with myInt
}
```

does not work? Why you need to know if there are numbers left?

**Edit** Changed to Ben's proposition.

Comment: As explained in the question, this would not distinguish between incorrect data in stream (say the representation of a double) and streams with nothing left in it.

Comment: @KRao: Yes it does, look at the state bits of the istream after extraction fails.

Comment: You don't need to call `.good()`, the stream overloads the `!` and boolean conversion operations.  Also the extraction returns the stream.  So you can say `if(!(myIstream >> myInt)) { /* separate eof from other failures */ }`

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I think that the first version before edit was different, and I replied to that one. But I may be wrong.

Comment: @KRao: When I say "KRao, look at the state bits", I expect YOU to add the missing code to check the state bits and see whether it's end-of-file or bad data.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to handle this situation is not to avoid reading from the stream, but to put back characters, which have been read, if needed:

```
int get_int(std::istream& in)
{
    int n = 0;
    while(true) {
        if (in >> n)
            return n;
        clean_input(in);
    }
}

void clean_input(std::istream& in)
{
    if (in.fail()) {
        in.clear();

        // throw away (skip) pending characters in input 
        // which are non-digits
        char ch;
        while (in >> ch) {
            if (isdigit(ch)) {
                // stuff digit back into the stream
                in.unget();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    error("No input");    // eof or bad
}
```